# Detect Symfony's internal subrequests in a twig view

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I want to integrate the FOSUserBundle's register and login forms in the same page:

[image]

To do that, I integrated the 2 forms using internal subrequests:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    {{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register', {'parent': true})) }}
</div>
```

And needed to edit [FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/92d5624f2a29e74d8fd9d2a94d7ed7998a8c2809/Resources/views/Registration/register.html.twig) to remove their "extends" and put nothing instead (as the layout is defined in a parent view).

But when accessing the `/register` routes (when user registered successfully for example), I need to extend my base layout, to render the registration confirmation view correctly.

[image]

To achieve this and use my base layout when needed, I did an ulgy trick in that `register.html.twig`:

```
{% 
    extends app.request.pathInfo == '/_fragment'
        ? "FOSUserBundle::empty.html.twig"
        : "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" 
%}
```

Is there a better way to detect if we're in a subrequest ? I looked for something like "hasParent" in requests, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something similar to what you're trying to do and ended up using an EL so you can create an Event Listener to check if the current request is a master or sub then use it as you wish. Full example is [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/zhyb/logging-users-master-and-systems-sub-requests-with-event-listener) and [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/dpv0/getting-full-information-about-the-request-with-on-kernel-controller-event-listener).

EL could be a onKernelController or a onKernelRequest. If you're happy to pass the variable to twig from your controller then use onKernelController which is what I used for similar reason.

**services.yml**

```
services:
    application_backend.listener.user_controller:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\EventListener\UserControllerListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

**Event Listener (onKernelRequest)**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class UserControllerListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $req = $event->isMasterRequest() ? 'Master' : 'Sub';
        $req = $event->getRequestType() ? 'Master' : 'Sub';

        //......
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it! Combined with a twig extension, it will be easily possible to move this information to twig views.

Comment: You're right, custom built twig extension is another way of doing it if you don't fancy dealing with it in controller.